# Explanation of this line of code?

Tags: java

Can you explain what is happening in this line of code? Specially what is `args[0].tocharArray` ?

```
char[] password = args[0].toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

char[] is your datatype. "char" is a single 16 bit character, and char[] is a character array.

args[0] is the first argument that's passed to the program.

.toCharArray(); converts that argument to a character array.

This line of code is basically taking an argument, turning it into a character array, and storing it in "password" which is a character array.

Answer (score 4):

It's converting the first argument of a Java program—passed as a `String[]` to the `main` method—to a character array.

Most password-oriented APIs use `char[]` so that after calling the method, the caller can "zero-ize" the array, effectively erasing the password from memory. Since Java `String` instances are immutable, they can't be zero-ized. However, in practice, it's hard to get user-input without using a `String`. All web frameworks will convert passwords submitted in a web request to a `String`. Swing password widgets and Java 6's `Console` class will input `char[]`, however.

Answer (score 3):

args<strike>[0]</strike> is presumably a String array. Thus it is a call to the method [String.toCharArray()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) which converts a String to an array of chars.

**EDIT**: Corrected my answer after comment.

Answer (score 2):

It converts the first item of the args array (presumably, the first command line argument passed to the `main` method, which is of string type) to an equivalent array of chars (an array containing all the chars that build up the string).

Answer (score 1):

args is an array.

The type of the array contains a function called toCharArray which returns an array of characters.  `NOTE:  args is most likely an array of strings`

So it takes the string in args[0] and creates an array of characters which represents that string.

Answer (score 0):

args[0] - representing a string 
toCharArray() - convert this string to char array

Answer (score 0):

I thought this, [toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29), might help.